# Does "peace of mind" require an article?

Tags: articles

Example:

> Buying insurance gives customers a peace of mind that their family will be protected in times of need.

Is an article needed or can I also say, "Buying insurance gives customers peace of mind..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peace of mind is a fixed expression in English that usually does not take an article. The only exception to this as far as I'm aware of is the quantifier 'some'.
In your example:
Correct: 'Buying insurance gives customers peace of mind that their family will be protected in times of need.'
Other examples: 'I hope that I can find peace of mind.'
'Knowing that your family is safe will give you at least some peace of mind.'

Answer (score 1):

This expression is found in  use with the indefinite article "a"; there are 95 hits on this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20peace%20of%20mind%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

It is  found rarely  with the article "the" as denoting uniqueness, as is the case for instance with  "*the sun*", "*the air*", etc., except in Indian English.

- ([ref. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Peace_of_Mind/oWU9AAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the+peace+of+mind%22&dq=%22the+peace+of+mind%22&printsec=frontcover)) By satisfying the demands of his lower impulses , he vainly expects to achieve what he has lost - the peace of mind . His ambition is lofty , his target is well chosen , but his search is in the wrong direction.
- ([ref. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Beyond_the_Silver_Linings/SFXwDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+peace+of+mind%22&pg=PT144&printsec=frontcover)) You understand that your money would not be able to buy the peace of mind for you.

As can be verified on this [page of research](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22peace+of+mind%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=zOcIYbidLYSNlwTw2IzgCA&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi4s--XopTyAhWExoUKHXAsA4w4ZBDy0wN6BAgBEEA&biw=1920&bih=1007&dpr=1) in an almost all cases this expression is used with zero article or the article "some" and other determiners such as "a little".

Nevertheless, when determined by postmodification, as in the sentence of the query (that their family will be protected…), then "the" is necessary. A hundred hits are found on this [page of Google research](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20peace%20of%20mind%20that%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

- ([ref. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Paying_for_Peace_of_Mind/aZvsAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the+peace+of+mind+that%22&dq=%22the+peace+of+mind+that%22&printsec=frontcover)) Some households place a high value on the  peace of mind that comes from being insured.
- ([ref. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Journal_of_the_American_Pharmaceutical_A/yvQaAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the+peace+of+mind+that%22&dq=%22the+peace+of+mind+that%22&printsec=frontcover)) Evidence showing that the addition of A DI You want the peace of mind that comes from the protection of American Druggists ' Insurance

However, the indefinite article "a" can also be used; it wouldn't do to use no article at all.